# Keyboard randomly freezes while typing

Tags: system-installation, display, settings, keyboard, hardware

While typing there are times where my keyboard randomly freezes and repeats the key over and over again. At that point, my only option is to manually hit the power button in order to restart. The shutdown button at the top right does not work.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is a bug in the latest kernel

this will fix it for you

```
sudo modprobe -r peaq_wmi

sudo modprobe -r eeepc_wmi
```