# USB Keyboard freezes

Tags: keyboard, usb

The USB keyboard connected to a 2011 iMac running the latest elementary os has stated randomly freezing, sometimes an unplug/replug works. Have tried an alternate keyboard same problem.

Tried this [Keyboard randomly freezes while typing](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15917/keyboard-randomly-freezes-while-typing)

No change.
Has been fine except for the last week? Any ideas? Did boot into the original Mac OS and that had no problems.